# PNG image is getting corrupted in Itext7

Tags: java, image, itext7

```
import static com.itextpdf.kernel.xmp.XMPUtils.decodeBase64;
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageData;
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory;

public  void testPngImage() throws XMPException {
    String orignalImage =  https://gist.github.com/nil96/d9d54200e5329211d2d7455492716500;
    String base64Image = orignalImage.replaceFirst("data:image/png;base64,","");
    byte[] decodedBytes = decodeBase64(base64Image);
    ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(decodedBytes,true);
    imageData.getData();
}
```

when I print `imageData.getData()` I get byte array containing -1 only. Whereas expected png byte array should start with `{-119, 80, 78, 71}`. This is only happening for PNG images. I can create jpeg images successfully. I have attached png in gist https://gist.github.com/nil96/d9d54200e5329211d2d7455492716500

Am I missing something for initializing Image or is it a bug?

Dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.7</version>
    <!--<version>7.1.8</version>-->
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As per documentation of itext7. PNG isn't supported in PDF, which is why iText will also decode PNG images into rw images. So we need to read it as raw image using function ImageDataFactory.createRawImage(decodedBytes);

Answer (score 1):

You appear to misunderstand the format of the data returned by `imageData.getData()`. You say

> expected png byte array should start with {-119, 80, 78, 71};

but `imageData` contains no PNG anymore, it contains data in the raw PDF bitmap image format.

Furthermore you inspected those data returned by `imageData.getData()` very superficially, you claim

> when I print imageData.getData() I get byte array containing -1 only

which is wrong: It indeed contains very many -1 entries but also some other byte values:

- 255898 times `-1`
- 12838 times `-2`
- 3126 times `-3`

etc etc

And this actually is not very surprising, after all your image is nearly pure white with a bit of scribble on it:

[image: the image]

The predominant white (RGB: 255, 255, 255) and near white (RGB values slightly smaller than 255) is the reason for the many `-1` (or as unsigned bytes: `255`), '-2' / '254', `-3` / `253`, ... values while the scribble is bringing in the few (unsigned) smaller bytes.

> Am I missing something for initializing Image or is it a bug?

First and foremost it is no iText bug but exactly what is to be expected.

The question is what you want to do with those image data which are merely meant for embedding in PDFs after compression. Usually, therefore, iText users don't call `getData()` here themselves but instead create an iText image object from the image data and add it to a PDF:

```
ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(...);
Image img = new Image(data);
```

and then

```
Document document = ...;
document.add(img);
```

or

```
Canvas canvas = ...;
canvas.add(img);
```

or even

```
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = ...;
pdfCanvas.addImage(data, ...);
```

and iText handles the actual image data under the hood.